# Invert a regular expression match in Overpass API

Tags: regex, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I want to search for possibly wrong ICAO codes using Overpass API. While matching an ICAO code is fairly trivial with the RegEx `^[A-Z]{4}$`, I'm trying to match everything that does *not* match this RegEx. How can I negate the RegEx?

I want to use this RegEx in the tool [Overpass-Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/).

Comment: You could try using a negative lookahead: `^(?![A-Z]{4}$).*`

Comment: Thanks for you input, but unfortunately this seems not to be supported.
`Error: line 8: static error: Invalid regular expression: "^(?![A-Z]{4}$).*"`

Comment: According to [this section](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Value_matches_regular_expression_(~,_!~)), you can use `!~` instead of `~` to match the opposite.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/429346/16217248).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Value_matches_regular_expression_(%7E,_!%7E)), you can use the `!~` operator to match the invert of `^[A-Z]{4}$`:

```
nwr["icao"!~"^[A-Z]{4}$"]
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you want to update the comment to the actual use case and put `nwr["icao"!~"^[A-Z]{4}$"]`?